# why does class cast does not take effect in java ternay operator

Tags: java

I have two methods:

```
public static void in(Object...objects) {
    System.out.println(objects);
}
public static void in(Collection<?> c){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

then I call these two methods

```
Object obj = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
in(obj); // [Ljava.lang.Object;@5b480cf9

in((List) obj); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Till now I have no problems, but I don't understand the output of this code:

```
in(obj instanceof List ? (List) obj : obj); // [Ljava.lang.Object;@6f496d9f
```

Why does it behave like this? I think it should be equivalent to `in((List)obj)`

Comment: Instead, using `obj instanceof List ? in((List) obj) : in(obj)` would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression has one, and only one compile-time type. The expression `obj instanceof List ? (List) obj : obj` can't possibly be of type `List`, since, if obj is not a List, its value is obj. So its type is Object.

To make it clearer (hopefully), you can't possibly do

```
List list = obj instanceof List ? (List) obj : obj;
```

it would try to assign the result of the ternary expression evaluation, which could be `obj`, of type Object, to a List.